# bibliography numbering

Tags: biblatex, numbering, biber

I'm using biblatex with the biber as follows

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
```

and my references show up beginning with the number 1. I would like to number them starting at the number 0. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is redifining the way `biblatex` displays the number of the reference, stored in the internal `labelnumber` field:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\decrease{#1}}

\newcounter{num}
\newcommand{\decrease}[1]{\setcounter{num}{#1}\addtocounter{num}{-1}\thenum}
```

In other words, the field is output as one less than it is. To achieve this, the value of `labelnumber` is stored in the counter `num` which is decreased by one and displayed by the macro `\decrease`.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! Ironically, I was referencing [Why numbering should start at zero](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html), and it was the first reference. Dijkstra would approve of your suggestion I think.

Comment: @hazelnusse Interesting ;) Although I'm not sure I entirely agree with him ....